# How to pass variables from PHP to Python and back?

Tags: python, php, shell-exec, sys

I have a PHP file and a Python file.
PHP File:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("python wamp64/www/PHP Test/TestPython.py 'param1' 'param2'")
?>
```

Python File:

```
import sys

x = sys.argv[1]
y = sys.argv[2]

print (x)
print (y)
```

When i run the PHP file it is not showing X and Y. The files are in the same folder and i have already tried to only put the file name instead of the full folder but that also does not work. Does anyone know why it's not working?
I'm using WAMP for PHP and Python 3.9.0.

Comment: Is it executing any Python at all?! `wamp64/www/PHP` and `Test/TestPython.py` are understood as two separate arguments for starters…

Comment: I'm kinda new to this, so i'm sorry if there are faults in it but as i said. I tried with only TestPython.py. That doesn't work.

Comment: What is the "wamp64/www/PHP" string for?

Comment: It is to navigate to the file but even if i just put the file name it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need an answer to your question, but after trying out a few things here and there on my local Windows computer, I think the issue might come down to the part in your PHP file where there is a space in the directory name. In particular, the "PHP Test" part. In Windows, from past experience and checking a little bit ago, when there are folder names that have a space in them, you need to somehow add quotes of some sort around the folder name (and I like to put double quotes around the entire file path if needing to do this).

So, based on the example that I tried on my local machine, if you were to change your PHP file to be something similar to this:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('python "wamp64/www/PHP Test/TestPython.py" "param1" "param2"')
?>
```

it might work as expected. I changed the types of quote marks that were used, so that the outer quote marks are single quotes and the inner quote marks are double quotes.

When I run an example like this *(note: "username" substituted for actual username):*

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('python "C:\Users\username\Documents\Space Text\TestPython.py" "param1" "param2"')
?>
```

I get this result *(note: "username" substituted for actual username):*

```
PS C:\Users\username\Downloads\php-7.4.15-nts-Win32-vc15-x64> .\php.exe C:\Users\username\Documents\"Space Text"\test.php
param1
param2
```

If that still doesn't work, I would make sure that you are using the full path to the `TestPython.py` file in your PHP code. To find the full path in Windows, I generally try to find the file in question (this time it would be `TestPython.py`) using the Windows File Explorer. Once you've found the file, if you click on the file path section of the Windows File Explorer heading, it should reduce the path into a line of text that can be copied and pasted into your PHP file. You might also need to add the final `TestPython.py` part at the end of this copy/pasted line.

[image: File Explorer Window]

Additionally, I haven't worked with WAMP as far as I can remember, so I don't know if the file path in your PHP code to the `TestPython.py` file needs to have anything in front of the `wamp64` part. For example, does the `wamp64` directory live somewhere on the `C:\` directory? If so, you might need to add the file path before the `wamp64` part if there is any; maybe something like `C:\path\to\wamp64\`. This part might not be necessary, though, but wanted to add that as a note.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. Assume that your directory is C:\Users\username\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\Project

```
Project
 |__ python_filename.py
 |__ php_filename.php
```

python_filename.py

```
import sys

x = sys.argv[1]
y = sys.argv[2]
print(x,y)
```

php_filename.php file

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("python /Users/username/Desktop/XAMPP/htdocs/Project/python_filename.py param1 param2")
?>
```

Output

```
param1 param2
```